# React Embedding Script Tag is Unstylable

Tags: javascript, css

I intend to embed a surveymonkey survey into my website (that is made with react). Just getting this to work was a hassle, but eventually this code worked:

```
let script = '<script>overly long link</script>';

let extractScript=/<script>(.+)<\/script>/gi.exec(script);
script = script.replace(extractScript[0], "");

class LeadForm extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        window.eval(extractScript[1]);
    }

    render() {
        return <div id="surveyMonkey" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: script}}/>;
    }
}
```

This works in that the surveymonkey renders, but it's stuck at the top left corner of the screen - making most of the website completely unusable. Any css styling on the div "surveyMonkey" does nothing.

Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: The code they gave me to embed the survey looks like this:

```
<script>(function(t,e,s,n){var o,a,c;t.SMCX=t.SMCX||[],e.getElementById(n)||(o=e.getElementsByTagName(s),a=o[o.length-1],c=e.createElement(s),c.type="text/javascript",c.async=!0,c.id=n,c.src=["https:"===location.protocol?"https://":"http://","widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/tRaiETqnLgj758hTBazgd2n0EyEqR4XLlegogsUllbowWHzPdjEQtkQpaEg2LAEE.js"].join(""),a.parentNode.insertBefore(c,a))})(window,document,"script","smcx-sdk");</script><a style="font: 12px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #999; text-decoration: none;" href=https://www.surveymonkey.com> Create your own user feedback survey </a>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's how you should be embedding the survey on your page?  The docs say to add it this way: [How to Embed Your Survey on a Website](https://www.surveymonkey.com/curiosity/how-to-embed-your-survey-on-a-website/).  In other words, don't set the body of the script in the way you are.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @zero298 & @Pambi , the below solution worked for me:

```js
class Survey extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    let el = document.createElement("script");
    el.src = "https://widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/tRaisffsdgj758hTBazgd4IXxGtDzETeaqu1iDMfLhIPM5OoAHZFDWBMRDTjq_2dfsd.js";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}

    render() {
      return <Container className="pageContainer">
      <Row className="homeRow">
      <div id="smcx-sdk"></div>   
      </Row>
    </Container>
    }
  }
  export default Survey
```

Comment: @zero298 Where you able to figure out how to detect when user finished the survey?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the documentation that you can find here: [How to Embed Your Survey on a Website](https://www.surveymonkey.com/curiosity/how-to-embed-your-survey-on-a-website/).  Looks like there is also an additional bit of documentation that you can find here: [Embedding Your Survey on a Website](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Website-Collector)

Don't use `eval`, and I would also stay away from `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` since you don't need it.  The fact that it has "dangerously" in the function name should give you pause.

[image: SurveyMonkey embed documentation]

Find the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag that you are provided and use it in the code below.

Then do something like this:

```
class LeadForm extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let el = document.createElement("script");
        el.src = "SOME_SCRIPT_SRC";
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }

    render() {
        return <div id="surveyMonkey"/>;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it seems like their tutorial may be outdated because the code that they gave me looks far different. They gave me loads more javascript. Check my original post to see the code they gave me. I tried your suggestion with the src being "widget.surveymonkey...LAEE.js" but no luck.

Comment: @ConnorW, Did you find more info about this? I'm trying to find a similar solution. Thx.

Comment: @JCGarcia unfortunately I couldn't find a solution to this exact problem and worked around it instead. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got embedding Surveymonkey on React site to work by adding `<div id="smcx-sdk"></div>` where I wanted to place the survey.

So the result is something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

class Survey extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div id="smcx-sdk"></div>
            <Helmet>
                <script 
                    src="https://widget.surveymonkey.com/collect/website/js/TOKEN.js" 
                    type="text/javascript"
                />
            </Helmet>
        )
    }
}
```

The url with the token is taken from the script they provide. Some styling can be done with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As of now what embedding code doing is attaching iframe with survey monkey src URL.

1. Embed script in simple HTML
2. Inspect for the iframe tag
3. You will find code similar to following

   `<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/XXXXX?embedded=1"></iframe>`
4. Copy iframe tag with attributes and place wherever you want.